# Read csv file using JavaScript and display into an html table

Tags: csv

I am a beginner in programming and I could really use your help to understand why this piece of code does not work and fix it. I get no error, simply nothing happens.

I want to read a csv file using JavaScript and display its contents in an html table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var fileInput = document.querySelector('notes.csv');
function read(callback){
    var file = fileInput.files.item(0);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e){
        callback(reader.result);
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
            var cells = rows[i].split(",");
            if (cells.length > 1){
                var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++){
                    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                    cell.innerHTML = cells[j];
                }
            }
        }
        var dvCSV = document.getElementById("dvCSV");
        dvCSV.innerHTML = "";
        dvCSV.appendChild(table);
    }
reader.readAsText(fileInput);
}
</script>

<div id="dvCSV"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add some `console.log(...)` in different code pieces to ensure that worflow goes as expected